# SQL - convert date from YYYY-MM-DD format to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Tags: mysql

I want to select an entire dataset and convert the `date_local` column from `YYYY-MM-DD` format to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`. I tried `CAST` and `Str_to_date` but apparently am not using them correctly.

Basic query is:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE country_name='Taiwan';
```

Here's the returned result:

| Row | rdbms_id | country_name | date_local | vendor_id | customer_id | gmv_local | is_voucher_used | is_successful_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 2870 | 3983 | 713.7 | false | false |
| 2 | 18 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 2870 | 3010 | 270.3 | false | false |
| 3 | 18 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 3812 | 3983 | 551.1 | false | false |
| 4 | 18 | Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 2870 | 43008 | 2532.33 | false | false |

I want to change the `date_local` column to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` format. Have tried the above functions but all are returned error messages.

Comment: Post some sample data, the expected results, the actual results,  and the query you're using. Without that all we can do is agree with you.

Comment: You want to convert from string to date_time? Try this "SELECT 
    STR_TO_DATE('2021-12-10', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
 as date;"

Comment: *I want to change the date_local column to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format.* Impossible. There is no "column format" in MySQL, the column datatype specifies the data retrieving format unconditionally. You must format your data to needed format in retrieving query. For example, use `SELECT .. , DATE_FORMAT(date_column, ''%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00') AS date_column, .. FROM Orders`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `date_local` column is a MySQL `DATE` column, and not a string-type column like `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, based on the sample output, you are probably looking for this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(date_local, @@session.time_zone, 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%dT%T');
```

However, you should understand that `DATE` columns have no time component, so the time will always be `00:00:00` which isn't particularly interesting.